# Сортировка при помощи uasort

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
$arr = [2,90,40];
```

Есть функция сортировки, которая «выталкивает» числа кратные 10 вверх списка:

```
function arrSort($a, $b)
{
    if ($a % 10 == 0 && $b % 10 == 0) return $a <=> $b;
    if ($a % 10 == 0 && $b % 10 != 0) return -1;
    if ($a % 10 != 0 && $b % 10 == 0) return 1;
    return ($a <=> $b);
}
```

Вызываем функцию:

```
uasort($arr, 'arrSort');
```

Получаем результат, который полностью решает нашу задачу:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 40
    [1] => 90
    [0] => 2
)
```

После выполнения работы функция сортировки возвращает следующие значения:

```
1) 2 % 10 != 0 && 90 % 10 == 0 return 1
2) 2 <=> 90: return -1
3) 40 % 10 == 0 && 90 % 10 == 0 return -1 
4) 40 <=> 90: return -1
```

Диагностику работы функции выполняю следующим образом:

```
function arrSort($a, $b)
{
    if ($a % 10 == 0 && $b % 10 == 0) echo "$a % 10 == 0 && $b % 10 == 0 <b> return " . ($a <=> $b) . "</b> <br />";
    if ($a % 10 == 0 && $b % 10 != 0) echo "$a % 10 == 0 && $b % 10 != 0 <b> return -1 </b> <br />";
    if ($a % 10 != 0 && $b % 10 == 0) echo "$a % 10 != 0 && $b % 10 == 0 <b> return 1 </b> <br />";
    echo "$a <=> $b: " . '<b> return ' . ($a <=> $b) . '</b>' . '<br />';

    if ($a % 10 == 0 && $b % 10 == 0) return $a <=> $b;
    if ($a % 10 == 0 && $b % 10 != 0) return -1;
    if ($a % 10 != 0 && $b % 10 == 0) return 1;
    return ($a <=> $b);
}
```

Вопрос: можете пошагово объяснить, как именно работает алгоритм, который помещает числа, кратные 10, вверх списка?

Comment: -1 значит, что сперва должен идти $a, а потом $b. 1 значит наоборот. Если ни одно из чисел не делится нацело на 10, то отрабатывает оператор `<=>`. Кстати, алгоритм неверный - он не сортирует часть, которая на 10 делится. Т.е.  `[2,90,40]` отсортируется как `[40,90,2]`, а `[2,40,90]` как `[90,40,2]` - косяк

Comment: Чтобы поправить, надо в самое начало добавить строку `if ($a % 10 == 0 && $b % 10 == 0) return $a <=> $b;`

Comment: @rjhdby спасибо за ответ. А Вы не знаете, почему на первом `2 % 10 != 0 && 90 % 10 == 0 return 1` и втором `2 <=> 90` шаге функция сортировки сравнивает одни и те же числа `$a` и `$b` (число `2` и число `90`)?

Comment: Вы как-то неправильно диагностику проводите. Сортировка отрабатывает всего за две итерации, как и должно быть. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c149b6150a27c580b95d941a51987aff773d0895

Comment: @rjhdby благодарю за код! Диагностику проводил внутри функции, которую указал в конце вопроса. Он неверен?

Comment: Конечно. Он вам на каждую итерацию будет по две строки печатать. Первую правильную, а вторую `echo "$a <=> $b: " . '<b> return ' . ($a <=> $b) . '</b>' . '<br />';
`

Comment: @rjhdby знаете, я последние 2 дня смотрю на эту функцию, но так до сих пор не понял, что за магия выталкивает кратные числа вверх массива.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97378/discussion-between-caboke-and-rjhdby).